# Como traer un total de consulta de mysql a php foreach

Tags: php

Tengo un problema, e intentado varias cosas pero no me da, hice una suma de dos hora tipo TIME en mysql y en el sql de phpmyadmin me da un total todo bien, pero cuando quiero traerme los datos en foreach en php  me salen todos los datos menos el de la suma total que es la que mas necesito no se si me falta algun parametro o algo, ya que en la vista me genera un error que el campo TotalHoras no existe, se que tengo que poner algun parametro pero la verdad es la primera vez que hago este tipo de consultas y no da con las que he probado, ojala me puedan ayudar muchas gracias de verdad que si

Esto es lo que tengo en mi vista:

```html
$item= null;
$valor=null;
$traerdatos = ControladorTraer::ctrtraertodo($item,$valor);
foreach ($traerdatos as $key => $value) {
    echo '<td>'.$value["nombre"].' </td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value["departamento"].' </td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value["TotalHoras"].' </td>';
    
}
```

ESTO ES LO QUE TENGO EN MI MODELO

```html
static public function MdlMostrarTodo ($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT *, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(hora_final1,hora_real )))) AS TotalHoras FROM $tabla ORDER BY id WHERE $item = $item");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();
        return $stmt -> fetch();

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla  ");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }
```

EN MI CONTROLADOR

```html
static public function ctrtraertodo($item, $valor){
            $tabla = "marcacion_entrada";
           $respuesta = ModeloTraer::MdlMostrarTodo($tabla, $item, $valor);

           return $respuesta;
```

Comment: Verificaste por cual de las dos condiciones esta pasando el programa? Es posible que el item esté llegando vacio y por eso no te genera el as TotalHoras y el programa esté pasando por el `else`?

Comment: `AS TotalHoras FROM $tabla` se encuentra en una rama del bloque `if `en la que nunca se entra porque la variable `$item` siempre es `null`: `$item= null;` y pasa a la rama `else`...

Comment: Si pasa por la rama del else esta sentencia SQL no se está ejecutando: `AS TotalHoras`

Comment: Aunque pase por esa rama le saldrá mal porque la consulta con `prepare` está mal hecha ( ¿¿ `$item = $item` ??) y en consecuencia su bindParam tambien. Léete https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare y https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam